# How to prevent Outlook from sending header with IP address and hostname

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook, vpn, email-client

Right now Outlook 2013 is sending each message with a header containing hostname, internal IP and external IP. How can this be stopped? This must take place on a local level because the computer is connected to the internet through VPN, the header can't be added on a remote server because the server would not be aware of the actual IP address.

Comment: What type of account do you use? I mean, Exchange/POP3+SMTP/IMAP/...?